# Trying to get property 'password' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
 Laravel change password thrown with the  message of Trying to get property 'password' of non-object", exception:
```

How tow solve the problem of message: Trying to get property 'password' of non-object", exception:
"ErrorException" Please help....................................

```
 public function updateAuthUserPassword(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'current' => 'required',
        'newpassword' => 'required',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:newpassword'
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    if (!Hash::check($request->current, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ['current'=> ['Current password does not match']]], 
    422);
    }

    $user->password = Hash::make($request->newpassword);
    $user->save();

    return $user;
    }
```

Comment: make sure $user not null

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
```

to

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
```

findOrFail will take an id and return a single model. If no matching model exist, it throws an ModelNotFoundException.
You can catch the exception using try catch block as well.

So you can write your complete code as

```
public function updateAuthUserPassword(Request $request)
 {
try{
   .... other codes
   $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
}catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
    // return with message that no user found.
}
```